# SW Reveal View Controller Right/ Localization

Tags: ios, localization, storyboard, swrevealviewcontroller

I've implemented a left side swrevealviewcontroller using storyboard but due to Arabic localization all the labels and icons in side menu goes right but side menu itself remain on left. Is there any chance I can tell revealviewcontroller to be open from right or left programatically?

I tried this line but it won't work:

```
[self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector( rightRevealToggle: )];
```

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: @BhavinRamani I've found the solution but you have to add your side menu and front view controller programatically. I'll post the code in the answer

Comment: @BhavinRamani I've posted my solution

Answer (score 0):

1. In my splash view controller, I'm creating Reveal View Controller first using storyboard ID
2. Then I'm creating my side menu view controller using storyboard ID
3. Then I'm creating my home view controller (Front View Controller) using storyboard ID
4. Either its Arabic or English front view controller will always be assigned using set Front method of reveal view controller
5. In the if else clause I'm checking if its English (In my case) I'm adding to right and in case of Arabic I'm adding my side menu to left.

#### CODE

```
let revealController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewControllerSBID") as? SWRevealViewController
let rearController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuVCSBID")
let frontViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVCSBID")
let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: frontViewController!)
revealController?.setFront(navigationController, animated: true)
    
if AppController.sharedInstance.language == "en" {
    revealController?.setRight(rearController, animated: true)
} else {
    revealController?.setRear(rearController, animated: true)
}
    
self.present(revealController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```